# Current character set: utf8 in response

Tags: php, json, apache, xampp, slim

Where is the debug information "Current character set: utf8" comming from?

It appears always first when I echoing something within my index.php (slim) script.

I really become desperate trying to suppress this.

May it caused by the .htaccess rules?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Here my setting:

Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36

The relevant section of the index.php:

```
function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
// Http response code
$app->status($status_code);
$app->config('debug', false);

// setting response content type to json
$app->contentType('application/json');
//$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show us (a relevant selection of) your index.php? Thought: could it be a message from your database connection layer?

Comment: @WilboBaggins Thx a lot, your tought was great, I found a printf in the DBConnect.php include...:-( shame on me :-)